# Windows 10 python Locust 'locust' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: python, windows-10, locust

I am following this tutorial:
https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/installation.html

Python version 3.9.4, used Visual Studio Code

Installed using

```
pip3 install locust
```

then paste and run

```
locust -V
```

and I see:

[image: error]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you see on the tutorial page that you linked, where it says "If everything worked, move on to Quick start. If it did not, check out the wiki for some solutions."? Well, it didn't work, obviously, so what happened when you clicked the link to the wiki and tried the suggestions there?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not tech support.

Comment: I dont mind this question, because even though I tried to make the documentation as clear as possible, people keep running into this issue (if nothing else, the question is good for people googling this particular error message :)

Comment: for the future, please don't post image with text, but directly text.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat common issue with Python on Windows.

As Karl mentioned, there is some info in the wiki: When running pip, did you get a warning saying `The script locust is installed in '...' which is not on PATH`? Add that directory to your PATH environment variable.